# Is masking required in this case?

Tags: c, optimization, masking

In the below code is the masking required for the assignment..

```
unsigned int x = 0x01020304;
unsigned char a1, a2, a3, a4;

a1 = (x >> 24) & 0xff;
a2 = (x >> 16) & 0xff;
a3 = (x >> 8) & 0xff;
a4 = x & 0xff ;
```

I do realize that it works well without it but I find these kind of assignments in all the standard/reviewed code... isn't it waste of cycles ??

Thank you for your responses for the above code it seems like the compiler has ignored(optimized) the masking as seen from the objdump below.

`a1 = (x >> 24) & 0xff;`

```
804838b:    8b 45 fc                mov    0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
804838e:    c1 e8 18                shr    $0x18,%eax
8048391:    88 45 fb                mov    %al,0xfffffffb(%ebp)
```

Comment: When I do something like this, I usually do the masking first and then the shift.

Comment: Thank you for your responses for the above code it seems like the compiler has ignored(optimized) the masking as seen from the objdump below.

unsigned int x = 0x01020304;
 8048384: c7 45 fc 04 03 02 01  movl   $0x1020304,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
unsigned char a1, a2, a3, a4;
a1 = (x >> 24) & 0xff;
 804838b: 8b 45 fc              mov    0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
 804838e: c1 e8 18              shr    $0x18,%eax
 8048391: 88 45 fb              mov    %al,0xfffffffb(%ebp)

Comment: not sure why im not able to paste it with proper formatting...

Comment: Code blocks doesn't work in comments. You can edit your post though and add it there.

Comment: yeh did that, but it would have been nice to show some diff that it is added later to the original post... new here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the masking code, since it clearly presents the intention of the author, which is to keep only the last 8 bits from each operation. The compiler is able to optimize it away (on platforms where a byte has exactly 8 bits), and on other platforms, the masking is necessary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's safer to do it this way. Imagine what would happen if `a1` was changed to an `int`.
It shouldn't be any slower as the compiler knows that casting to a char involves masking several bits.

Interestingly, `0xff` may not always be the correct mask - `UCHAR_MAX` from `stdint.h` will be platform independent.

Comment: Citation is wrong. It does not apply to assignments, which invoke implicit conversions, and even if it did, unsigned arithmetic is always modular arithmetic and has no exceptional values.

Comment: @R.. Could you give me a citation? I'm having a hard time finding that.

Comment: 6.5.16.1: "In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand." And 6.3.1.3: "if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type."

Comment: BTW about your edit at the end, 0xff is definitely the correct mask, and in fact it's necessary to get the desired behavior if `CHAR_BIT>8`.

Comment: @R.. Thanks for pointing that out. Hopefully the revision is now correct.

Answer (score 0):

For all practical purposes, you're fine without the mask. But according to spec, you need the mask since the actual size of a char is architecture dependent, and in this case I reckon you should hope that it's size is at least 8 bits (again, not guaranteed, based on architecture).

No, I can't cite any modern machines that aren't using 8-bit bytes (thus the "all practical purposes" disclaimer). But many old machines  in the past certainly did not.

Comment: I thought the standard said that `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1

Comment: @SethCarnegie sizeof(char) is 1 byte, but standard doesn't specify number of bits per byte

Answer (score -2):

For most systems with 8-bit char, the masking is unnecessary and visually ugly, but it makes no difference to the generated code unless your compiler fails to perform any optimization. If `CHAR_BIT>8`, then the explicit masking is necessary to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is - expand the code a little to look like this with the shifts already done.

```
a1=0x01 & 0xff // ok not really needed here
a2=0x0102 & 0xff // needed here because I just want the 02 from the hex
a3=0x010304 & 0xff // needed here because I just want the 04 from the hex
a4=0x01020405 & 0xff // needed again because I just want the 05 from the hex
```

Comment: But he's asking why you need the `& 0xff` if the type is `unsigned char` and it can only hold 8 bits anyway.

Comment: And the `x` is probably not a constant expression, but a function parameter, so your optimization will not be applicable in practice.

Comment: Right - so how does the compiler know which set of bits to assign depending on its alignment - high order / low order - bits in the midddle? Using 0xFF says I want the 8 low order bits. Oh and char is guaranteed to hold up to 127 but nothing says it cant hold more?

Comment: It would always give the lowest 8 bits anyway.

Comment: @SethCarnegie This question is about C, which doesn't require that `unsigned char` be restricted to eight bits.

Comment: @Roland - what optimization did I specify?

Comment: Agree with Huw - nothing in spec say char has to be 8 bits